# Yii2 ListView summary unknown property

Tags: listview, yii2, summary

When I try to run the following code

```
<?=
ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_fichaRevista',
    'summary ' => '',
]);
?>
```

I get this Exception:

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
>
> Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ListView::summary

Why?

According to the [**`documentation`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html) **`summary`** property is correct. 
What is going wrong?

Comment: can you select the answer as correct if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have a `white-space` in the property name `summary` in the end remove it and it will work or copy paste from below

```
<?=
ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_fichaRevista',
    'summary' => '',
]);
?>
```

Comment: Wow! Why I couldn't see that! Thank you very much Muchammad!